# Opening and closing multiple .csv files in R

Tags: r

I need to summarise a .csv file in R that have 12GB of data. I divided the .csv in multiple files, so I can load them, but for this I have to read the files and close them before reading the next ones. How can I do it? Is the `rm()` function inside the loop enough?

EDIT:

the solution i thought was this:

```
files <- list.files(path = "/path", pattern = ".csv")

for (i in 1:lenght(files)) {
  temp <- read.csv(files[i], sep = ";", header = TRUE)

  dosomething(temp)

  rm(temp)
}
```

But I don't know if this will remove the variables from my RAM so i load them all.

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: When you pass a file to `read.csv` (and similar functions), it opens the file, reads the data, then closes the data, so you do not need to worry about still-open connections in this context. If you are concerned about memory (and garbage collection, the process for freeing memory for no-longer-referenced objects), though, you can look at `gc` and similar topics. Another thought, though, is to make sure the operations you're doing on the data are done efficiently ... and depending on those, memory-efficient topics often reference the `data.table` package.

Comment: the solution i thought was this:
```files <- list.files(path = "/path", pattern = ".csv")

for i in range(1:lenght(files)) {
  temp <- read.csv(files[i], sep = ";", header = TRUE)
  
  dosomething(temp)
  
  rm(temp)
}```
But I don't know if this will remove the variables from my RAM so i load them all.

Comment: I think you're confusing python and R code. Specifically `for i in range(...)` is very python-esque but is wrong in R. I suggest `for (fn in files) { temp <- read.csv(fn,...); do_something(); rm(temp); gc(); }`.